# Create custom payment gateway in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, class, methods, interface

Which class we need to extends,implement interface and method use when create a custom payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

[Check magento sample module for payment gateway](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway)

[For more detail check magento devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html)

Most important part is Facade Configuration. Check from here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/facade-configuration.html

OxiPay module is developed using payment gateway. and this is simple module.
https://github.com/oxipay/oxipay-magento-2.x